# Is it possible to build Android apps directly on an Android device?

Tags: android, android-studio, termux

I'm developing an android project on my laptop using android studio, But I have plenty of time in bus or submarine that I dont access to my laptop, but my  **rooted**  android tablet is available, I have installed [termux app](https://termux.com/) On my tablet, so I have access to linux environment from my phone, but using this app it is not  [possible](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/2864) to build android studio projects.
One solution is to install one linux distribution like ubuntu on tablet, and install android studio, but running a complete linux on android tablet is too lazy.
There is an app on google play,  [apk builder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailsid=com.gmail.heagoo.apkbuilder)  but it couldn't build my project and there is some error.
So my question is :
Is There Any Way To Build Android Studio Project On Android Device?